Is there real-time validation of the license key in TinyMCE?
I'm working with TinyMCE version 7 and noticed a potential issue with the license key validation. In the tinymce.js file, the license_key configuration option seems to only check the length of the provided key to determine its validity. This means that if I supply a random key that satisfies the length requirement, it passes as valid.
I experimented by providing various random keys that matched the required length, and they all seemed to work without any issues. Given this, I have doubts about whether TinyMCE performs any real-time validation of the license key beyond this basic length check.
I expected that TinyMCE would have some form of real-time or server-side validation to ensure the license key is genuinely valid, rather than just relying on the length of the key.

Your observation that it only checks for size is correct. You can also edit the check to do nothing. The license key is more of an indication whether you promise to adhere to the gpl terms or claim to have a commercial license. It is possible the authors have measures in place to scan for bogus keys in use and could come after you if you lie.
